# OCaml - "module" or "open" or [opt_rec] expected after "let" error

Tags: ocaml

So I have the following code:

```
let rec take k list acc = match list with
| [] -> failwith "empty list"
| x::xs when k = 0 -> x, acc @ xs
| x::xs -> take (k - 1) xs (acc @ [x]);;

let rec random_p l acc = match l with
| [] -> acc
| [x] -> acc @ [x]
| x::xs -> let r = (Random.int (List.length l)) in let val, rest = take r (x::xs) [] in random_p rest (acc@[val])
```

However when I try to enter the second function, I get the error

```
Parse error: "module" or "open" or [opt_rec] expected after "let" (in [expr])
```

with the second 'let' in the final line underlined as the source of the error. I tried it with and without the Random function beforehand, but always get this error. I can't work out what the problem is, I've used in and let in virtually the same way in other code without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that `val` is a keyword. If you replace it by `val_`, `v`, or anything else that is not a keyword, you should get past this error.